# Cannot get my 'delete.php to send to db and mark as dead

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is this an id problem or is there something I am missing? I am trying to get it to delete a comment...On this 'delete.php' page, $prof is the user sending the delete request, on the page that I'm trying to delete from, $auth is the sender of the comment.

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/system/init.php');
    enforce_auth();

    $prof = new User($_GET['id']);

    $query = "UPDATE `ProfileComments` SET `status` = 'dead' WHERE `id` = '".$prof->id."' LIMIT 1";
    $request = mysql_query($query,$connection);
?>
```

should I replace a different variable in the query instead of `$prof->id` ?

Comment: I'm really hope you escape EVERY variables that comes from the user!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I see it, I think it's overkill to make a new object when you're just using the id to update your database :)

I would do it like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; <br>
mysql_query("UPDATE ProfileComments SET status = 'dead' WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

See if that should do the trick!

Comment: Escaping. Escaping. Escaping.

Comment: sorry ;) I'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: That has nothing to do with being new or not. Pasting sample code that's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks doesn't help at all in my eyes.

Comment: @Franz, was my original code more on the right track? I really think it's an id problem, not getting any errors, echo the query and it looks right, just not getting rid of comment or marking it dead in db

Comment: Thought by "escaping" he meant "format your code before posting!" But you're right about escaping (thanks SleighBoy). There's no need to be rude though - wasn't really doing it by purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Just type in your application:

```
echo $query = "UPDATE ProfileComments SET status = 'dead' WHERE id = '".$prof->id."' LIMIT 1";
```

That will ouput the query as a string. If you can see the error immediatly, great. If not try to paste it into [`phpMyAdmin`](http://www.phpmyadmin.net). This should really help you debug your MySQL!

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 for this simple and effective teqnique. That is what I use whenever I get stuck with query.

Answer (score 0):

This will escape data and cast the id as an integer, which it should be in this case.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ProfileComments SET status = 'dead' WHERE id = '". mysql_real_escape_string((int)$prof->id) . "' LIMIT 1");
```